# Looking for an idiom or expression synonymous with "where force fails, skill and patience will prevail"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for an idiom or expression, conveying the same meaning as this one - Where force fails, skill and patience will prevail. I do not know whether this one is used in English, so I am looking for a different one. The implication is that  one finds another way to do something, using his wit and acumen, instead of doing it with physical force. For example:

1. He is a sharp-witted person. Instead of carrying wood logs down to his basement by hand, he came up with an idea of using a treadmill to finish the job.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is "brain over brawn". it might not be an expression, but it is simple and clean, and pretty much what you mean.

Comment: Somewhat related is "the pen is mightier than the sword."

Comment: I find nothing wrong with your phrase in the first place. It may not be a set phrase that's used all the time (although it sounds like it *should* be), but it's perfectly understandable, conveys exactly what you want, and even rhymes. I don't think that using something else would be preferable.

Comment: I thought of 'less is more' but I think it needs more.

Answer (score 1):

**Attack by Stratagem**  Sun Tzu  [SunTzuSaid](https://suntzusaid.com/book/3)

> Hence to fight and conquer in all your battles is not supreme
>   excellence; supreme excellence consists in breaking the enemy's
>   resistance without fighting.

Answer (score 0):

Work smart, not hard

Your brain is the most powerful muscle in your body

The Mind Is The Body's Strongest Muscle

Comment: The nearly rhyming "smarter, not harder" is more common in my experience.